# Bluetooth not working - Debian

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

Result of "inxi -Fxxxrz"

```
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-3:2 chip-ID: 0489:e0c8 class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: <filter>
```

inxi results shows the bluetooth device, but i cannot enable and use it, i tried with "systemctl", but no use

In Windows 11 Bluetooth works fine,

While viewing dmesg

```
sudo dmesg  |grep -i blue

[    3.844492] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.844518] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.844520] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.844524] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.844527] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.844531] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.972678] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.972681] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.972684] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.896002] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

```
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-3:2 chip-ID: 0489:e0c8 class-ID: e001
```

Because the device manufacturer (Foxconn) has replaced the Bluetooth chip manufacturer's USB vendor/product ID code with their own, your Linux kernel version cannot identify this Bluetooth chip by exact chip type.

The `class-ID: e001` suggests that the device may claim to be a generic USB Bluetooth device (USB device class `e0`, subclass `01`, programming interface `01` - unfortunately `inxi` won't display the last part), and so Linux tries to use it like a generic USB Bluetooth device.

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

However, it does not work as expected.

Looking at [a list of known Foxconn USB device IDs](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0489), it seems they have previously used various Broadcom and Atheros bluetooth chips. Many Broadcom chips will require that a firmware file is sent to the device at start-up, before the device will work. The firmware and the sending method can be specific to each chip model. Other chips may have other special requirements.

[The patch for this has already been submitted in April 2022](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-mediatek/patch/1b7d9428ba0c6d572d7da1da166240833350786e.1651082524.git.objelf@gmail.com/): apparently a MediaTek employee reported that the device is actually using a MediaTek MT7921 chip. [The patch is already included in the 5.19-rc1 pre-release kernel:](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?h=v5.19-rc1#n454) once kernel version 5.19 is fully released, any stable and long-term maintained kernels are likely to also get the patch backported to them, as the backporting looks to be very simple.

If you cannot wait, and can compile a custom kernel for yourself, the fix submission email (linked above) has the code you'll need to add to your kernel.

Comment: The relevant IDs have been added in Kernel 6.1 (apparently not in 6.0).
(so you don't need to install a fully custom kernel)