# Bluetooth not working: Bluetooth-device not reccognized, because updated product/verndor-id missing in kernel (e.g. in HP Envy 360)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, bluetooth

On my new HP Envy x360 Laptop using Ubuntu 22.10 I cannot start bluetooth (my research suggests that other distros must be affected likewise because the source lies in the kernel).

I have done all the relevant tests. The bluethooth device is active and unblocked etc.

I found out that the manufacturer for the bluetooth device has changed the vendor/product ID, therefore Linux does not properly recognize the device.

[Bluetooth not working - Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705772/bluetooth-not-working-debian)

> Because the device manufacturer (Foxconn) has replaced the Bluetooth
> chip manufacturer's USB vendor/product ID code with their own, your
> Linux kernel version cannot identify this Bluetooth chip by exact chip
> type.
>
> The class-ID: e001 suggests that the device may claim to be a generic
> USB Bluetooth device (USB device class e0, subclass 01, programming
> interface 01 - unfortunately inxi won't display the last part), and so
> Linux tries to use it like a generic USB Bluetooth device.

The poster of the aforementioned answer suggests to recompile a patched kernel or wait.

I had hoped that in the latest kernel 6.0 might already contain the corrections. This does not seem to be the case; installing the latest ubuntu mainline kernel did not help.

== UPDATE ==

The relevant addition of the IDs apparently didn't make it into kernel version 6.0 but only in 6.1.

Sadly -- at the time of wiring -- version 6.1 of the "Ubuntu-edition" of the kernel is not yet fully ready, only the non-final version "v6.1-rc5" is available ([Ubuntu Mainline kernels by the Ubuntu Kernel Team](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/))

So my only remaining questions is:

- Is there really no other formal way to temporally change or add a vendor/product IDs?